# Index in fraction in exponent in fraction looks wonky

Tags: formatting, fractions

I'm trying to write

```
\[ \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}}} \]
```

but it looks really  wonky. In particular the B in the subscript is just as big as everything else. I've seen this written in a way that looked nice (without using \exp or writing (...)/(...) instead of \frac{}{}. Is there any nicer way of doing this?

Comment: I would always recommend the exp syntax when the argument get complicated, easier to understand for the reader. Perhaps even combined with / instead of the fraction

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the following four representations of the same mathematical expression.

[image]

- The first row is from your posting. TeX knows about scriptstyle (for first-level subscripts and superscripts) and scriptscriptstyle (for second-level subscripts and superscripts) math, but not about scriptscriptscriptstyle. That's why the letter `B` looks too big relative to `k` and `T`.
- The second row succeeds in making the overall expression less tall, by replacing `\frac{1}{...}` with `[...]^{-1}`. However, the letter `B` still looks too big.
- The third row replaces `e^{...}` with `\exp(...)`. This change, finally, succeeds in getting the relative sizes about right.
- The fourth row replaces `frac{a}{b}` with `(a)/(b)`, with inline-fraction notation.

In my view, the expressions in rows 3 and 4 both look good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\addtolength\jot{4pt}
\begin{align*} 
&\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}}} \\
&\Bigl[1+e^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}}\Bigr]^{-1} \\
&\Bigl[1+\exp\Bigl(\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}\Bigr)\Bigr]^{-1} \\
&\bigl[1+\exp\bigl((\varepsilon-\mu)/(k_B T)\bigr)\bigr]^{-1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use`\tfrac` in the exponent (and `\mathrm{e}`, but that's another problem). Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}}} \]

\[ \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{\tfrac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_B T}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to have a smaller `B` you can use `scalerel` package with the command `\scaleobj`.
Here's an example with a scaling factor of `0.7`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[ \frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{k_{\scaleobj{.7}{B}} T}}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Scaling the letter `B` down seems, to me, preferable to using `\tfrac`, which in the present expression generates an overly large exponent term that towers over the letter `e`.